# Multiclass classification (gradient boosted trees) predictions distribution using softmax()

Tags: classification, multiclass-classification, distribution, lightgbm

Let's consider a multiclass problem where the target is composed by 20% class 'A', 50% of class 'B' and 30% of class 'C'.

The model is trained and then the class predictions are obtained via the softmax function (as per max probability among the 3 classes for each row) to predict one of {A,B,C}. I was expecting the outcome to reproduce the distribution of the original target, i.e., 20%, 50% and 30%, but it's not the case (even scoring the same training set), getting 5%, 85%, 10%, resp.

Is that expected? Under what circumstances this could happen?

Comment: It is possible to build bad models, even on your own training set. So, expected maybe, maybe not. But possible for sure!

Comment: We need more information to properly answer this question. Which is the predicted output distribution that you think is a problem? Your features are informative? Are you using which softmax function exactly?

Comment: Edited question to clarify the points above